# Primefaces Progress Bar Not Get Updated

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/progressBar.xhtml) along with JSF 2.0 and I want to update message on increasing value of progress bar.

In this example it uses  `<p:ajax event="complete" />` while its not working on `event="change"` it says `Event:change is not supported.`
is there is any alternate way?

Some Code (xhtml):

```
<p:fileUpload id="uploader" header="File Upload" style="font-size:12px;"
fileUploadListener="#{addAgent.FileUpload}" rendered="true"
mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" update="Label"
ajax="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|XLS)$/" onstart="PF('pbAjax').start(); PF('statusDialog').show()"/> 
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

<p:progressBar interval="1000" id="progressBar" widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{addAgent.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false">
<p:ajax event="complete" update="messages Label"/>
</p:progressBar>

<h:outputLabel for="uploader" style="font-size:15px;" id="Label" value="#{addAgent.Status }"/>
```

ManagedBean:

```
while (rows.hasNext()) {
   progress++;
   setStatus(progress+"");
}
   // getter Setter
```

Comment: post your xhtml and managedbean code

Comment: i edit the question for some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) Component, to update your message component each second, or whatever you like. Triggered by `commandButton` that also trigger your progress bar.